# EXCEL - reverse lookup in a matrix

Tags: excel, lookup, vlookup

I have the situation of the picture

[image: situation].

A table and two data: a rating value and another value. I need to look up to the matrix along the right row based on the current rating and sweep horizontally based on the input value and get the nearest smaller rating.

So in this case, I'm expecting 2. If the rating were 2, then results should be 3 and with 3, then 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:D1,MATCH(B7,INDEX(B2:D4,MATCH(B6,A2:A4,0),0)))
```

[image]

The inner INDEX/MATCH sets the proper range.  While the outer finds the first time that the value number is equal to  or less than and the next is greater than.

EDIT: As per the OP's comment

If you want the next column just add one:

```
=INDEX(B1:D1,IFERROR(MATCH(B7,INDEX(B2:D4,MATCH(B6,A2:A4,0),0))+1,1))
```

The IFERROR deals with the times that the value is less than the first number in the series.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks!! however, I was wrong and with rating 1 and value 0,6 I should get 2 as we passed the rating 1. what should I change there? thanks!

Comment: yeah!! super!! when I see, it was not too complicated but honestly, I really couldn't do it! :) thanks a lot!

Comment: just a comment. if you put 0.1, it doesn't work... :(